# GCC not working on macOS Majave?

Tags: macos, homebrew, xcode, gcc

I am trying to download some astronomy software ([PINT](https://nanograv-pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)) and when I perform `make test`, as suggested, it fails. I believe the problem is with my gcc compiler on my Mac. The error I am given is

$ Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmpc.3.dylib

$ Referenced from: /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0/8.3.0/cc1

$ Reason: image not found

gcc: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 signal terminated program cc1

Please submit a full big report...

$ error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4

I am fairly new to software/Linux/computer stuff, and have a feeling there may be an easy fix to this but I'm not sure what.

I have installed Homebrew, and with that a gcc compiler. I followed the advice given [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8336714) and it did not fix the issue.

If any additional information is needed for help with this question let me know. Anything is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had updated my mpc/mpfr libraries via homebrew. The software I am using requires earlier versions of them; the solution was to re-download mpfr from [here](https://github.com/ksomemo/homebrew-mpfr-3/blob/master/README.md) and move over the libraries that were missing to the appropriate directory.

So in short, (1) I downloaded an older version of mpfr, (2) copied the needed libraries (libmpc.3.dylib, libmpfr.4.dylib) over to /usr/local/lib (`cp libmpfr.4.dylib /usr/local/lib`), (3) and continued to run the installation command for PINT to see what other files needed to be moved over. More issues kept popping up, and the solutions are covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457773/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libmpfr-4-dylib).

Answer (score 0):

You might have libmpc upgraded without reinstalling or upgrading gcc, so gcc is looking for a missing version of libmpc.

```
$ brew reinstall gcc
```

should fix the problem. Otherwise try

```
$ brew reinstall libmpc gcc
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the issue, I am still getting the same errors